# How did all these monuments end up together in one place?

Tags: resident-evil, resident-evil-extinction

In *Resident Evil: Extinction*, how did every monument like Eiffel Tower and the Statue of Liberty get together here? 
(I think there is pyramid also on the left. Screenshot at 55:04)

[image: Sandy landscape with several famous monuments: Sphinx, Eiffel Tower, etc]

Comment: This is Vegas, there are copies of these known buildings/structures.

Comment: In the 2600s, New Yorkers elected a super villain governor, and he stole most of the world’s monuments.

Comment: @zero298 Carmen Sandiego was elect governor of New York?

Comment: This being Resident Evil, I'm sure the Umbrella Corporation are somehow to blame ....

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This is because they were in Las Vegas, for instance, where the Sphinx and Pyramid in your screenshot is where The Luxor Hotel is.

[image: Outside of The Luxor]

The other landmarks can also be found in Vegas as mentioned in [this website about Las Vegas strip](https://theplanetd.com/vegas-strip-landmarks/)

It is mentioned in the movie that the group needed to go to Vegas in order to get fuel to go for the trip to Alaska where it was thought to be Infection free.

Obviously these are only replicas of the real things and for the purpose of the movie production, are replicas of the replicas.

Comment: so all these is nothing but just a replica made at The Luxor Hotel ?

Comment: @MikunjRathwa Not all. Just the sphinx.  The other monuments belong to other hotels along the Vegas strip.

Comment: Although much of the _real_ London Bridge is in Lake Havasu City Arizona, just a short jaunt to the south (unless blocked by undead, of course).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Indeed, though the only reason that this is interesting is that people confuse the rather mundane [London Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_Bridge_(Lake_Havasu_City)) with the much more dramatic [Tower Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_Bridge).

Comment: @DavidRicherby *A* real London Bridge...

Comment: @DavidRicherby It was interesting to me and I didn't know about it until just now. Imagine moving a bridge from London to Arizona of all places.

Comment: The only thing I know about the London Bridge is that it has a tendency to fall down.

Comment: @origimbo Too bad about the one that fell down.

Comment: The London Bridge that the song was about was much more impressive in its own way - it had buildings on it and everything (The buildings were removed in ~1760, and the bridge was replaced in 1831).

Comment: @KodosJohnson Yeah, you're right -- that's interesting on its own. Bad phrasing on my part.